# Is it possible to reuse the UIScrollView scrolling physics for a custom scrolling view?

Tags: uiscrollview

I have a custom view with some complex scrolling behaviour. I’d like the scrolling to have the same physics as `UIScrollView`, both the inertia and the edge bouncing. Is it possible to somehow reuse the physics code from `UIScrollView` to save effort and offer a consistent user experience?

Answer (score 0):

It’s sort of a hack, but it can be done. The solution is nicely explained in the [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) Session #223: [Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=223). The main trick is to place a regular `UIScrollView` over your content, watch for the offset changes reported by the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate call and adjust your custom view’s content accordingly. The only catch is accepting other touch input (as the scroll view covers your real content view and swallows the input), but even this is reasonably easy to solve, as shown in the WWDC video.